# Text properties overriden in org-agenda header

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, text-properties

I do load a sexp entry - as a diary- from one of my agenda files which calls a custom function. Everything works fine except that the propertized text using utf glyphs is overriden in the agenda view as `org-agenda-calendar-sexp`.

The entry in the org file looks like:

```
* Data for a given day
     :PROPERTIES:
     :CATEGORY: data
     :END:

%%(myFunction)
```

Where `myFunction` returns a string made out of a data concatenation gathered from several weather forecast network places, which, simplified, looks like this:

```lisp
(concat "test line :\t" 
        #("\uf055" 0 1 (font-lock-face (:family "Weather Icons" :height 1.2 ))))
```

Once the agenda is built, the line is there with correct data but:

**What I expect** is having the line with the glyph displayed using *Weather Icon* font family, as it does in any other buffer using font-lock if I `insert` that string.

**What I get** is the same line using my system default unicode font family for `\uf055` glyph, as `org-agenda-calendar-sexp` face.

## Question is

How I can keep the properties I've set first?
Alternatively, where can I find `%%()` implementation?.

## Related relevant questions which I've read before asking:

- [Why does `insert` not insert colorized text?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/56221/why-does-insert-not-insert-colorized-text)
- [Propertize org-agenda-overriding-header](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/52488/propertize-org-agenda-overriding-header)

  accepted answer's section two may work, but I'd rather give up using propertized text before using such convoluted approach for a small thing like this.

Comment: I can't follow your description of the problem. Could you edit your question and add some additional detaila of what you do and what goes wrong? E.g. If I take the *result* of the the `(concat ...)` call and make that a header in an Org mode agenda file, and I display the agenda, the header appears intact.

Comment: @NickD hope now is enough ;)

Comment: Yes, thank you - that's much clearer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are seeing, so maybe I'm wrong but I don't think I can reproduce your problem. The character I see ( a solid circle with a dark + in the middle) is the same in the agenda as it is any other buffer. When I do `C-u C-x =` on it, I see that the face is `org-agenda-calendar-sexp` but there is  a `font-lock-face       (:family "Weather Icons" :height 1.2)` as well. Maybe you can add a screen shot of how it looks in your agenda?

Comment: @NickD Looks exactly like yours, and after some tweaking I get the properties there, but characters aren't displayed with "weather icons"